# Different outcomes when using tf.Variable() and tf.get_variable()

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to get familiar with TensorFlow framework from [this site](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs20si/syllabus.html) by playing around with Linear Regression (LR). The source code for LR can be found [here](https://github.com/trdngy/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials/tree/master/examples), with the name `03_linear_regression_sol.py`.

Generally, the defined model for LR is  `Y_predicted = X * w + b`, where

- `w` and `b` are parameters (`tf.Variable`)
- `Y_predicted` and `X` are training data (`placeholder`)

For `w` and `b`, in the sample code, they are defined as following

```
w = tf.Variable(0.0, name='weights')
b = tf.Variable(0.0, name='bias')
```

And I changed these two lines of code a little bit as following

```
w = tf.get_variable('weights', [], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.get_variable('bias', [], dtype=tf.float32)
```

For this experiment, I got two different `total_loss/n_samples` for those two versions. More specifically, in the original version, I got a deterministic result at anytime, `1539.0050282141283`. But, in the modified version, I got undeterministic results at different running time, for example, `total_loss/n_samples` could be `1531.3039793868859`, `1526.3752814714044`, ... etc.

What is the difference between `tf.Variable()` and `tf.get_variable()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) accepts an initial value upon creation (a constant), this explains deterministic results when you use it.

[`tf.get_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable) is slightly different: it has an `initializer` argument, by default `None`, which is interpreted like this:

> If `initializer` is `None` (the default), the default initializer passed in the variable scope will be used. If that one is `None` too, a `glorot_uniform_initializer` will be used.

Since you didn't pass an initializer, the variable got uniform random initial value.

Comment: In the execution phase, I already had the line of code `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` for both versions. I thought this line takes responsibility of initializing variables, doesn't it? Anyway, after adding the initializer for variables, `w = tf.get_variable('weights', [], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)` and `b = tf.get_variable('bias', [], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
`, I got the deterministic values! Great!

Comment: Yes, this line - `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` - runs the initializers for all variables. The result boils down to whether these initializers are constant or random.